# get all html elements (the names or ids) in order of appearance on a form using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, names

At work I have a a few html forms (classic asp back) with normal html elements and classic asp dynamic check boxes.

We want to do reporting on this and create pivot tables so I need to provide a list of all the names or ids (names is probably better) of html objects (static and dynamic) in the order they appear on the form. Some are hidden until the user interacts with depending object (we want those too).

I found multiple posts about getting all withing a class but could find this exact answer because the order is very important!

jQuery is already being used on the page so that would be fine to use.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That sounds like a fairly comprehensive assignment; where did you start? How did it go? What went wrong?

Comment: Beware: order of appearance on the screen is not always the order in the HTML. Sounds tricky.

Comment: I already created the forms and the dynamic checkboxes (from ms sql). There are a few hidden texts that show when selecting 'other' in a dropdown. I started by building the html forms then making sure they post and save correctly. Then I added the dynamic checkboxes and did js validation on the required fields and now I need to prepare for the reporting. Everything went well (a bit convoluted) but this reporting piece is giving me grief!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either option to create a list of element IDs/names within `#myForm`:

```
var orderedArrayId = [];
$("#myForm *[id]").each(function(){
    orderedArrayId.push(this.id);
})

var orderedArrayName = [];
$("#myForm *[name]").each(function(){
    orderedArrayName.push(this.name);
})
```

Instead of using `.push(this.id)`, you can also use `.push(this)`, if you want to get a list of DOM elements.

After running this code, you can loop through all elements:

```
$.each(orderedArrayId, function(index, element){
    //element holds the ID of the element
    // (or a reference to the DOM element, if you've used `.push(this)` instead
    //      of `.push(this.id)`)
    //Do something
});
```

Comment: This works fine. Kind of. I probably should have explained a bit more but didn't think it necessary. I have 1 master page (main.asp) and inside that is the form tag name/id = frmMain. Below that I do some classic asp spaghetti logic and then include the appropriate html/asp form.
`<!--#include Virtual="UO/WebSF/frmAggressiveBehavior/frmAggressiveBehavior.asp"-->`
I dont think that the html objects within these include files are getting caught by your script because I only see the ones that are within the frmMain but not in the include.

Any tips?

Comment: So, you've got multiple forms? Loop through each form.